# How to get image name from website?

Tags: android, image, blocked

I've not been successful in searching for this answer, but basically, how can I find the image file name from a website that blocks saving of the images?  Normally, the url source will have the image filename and it is easily searchable.

However, some sites lets you hover over the picture and it then zooms to a larger image.  The source shows, 
for example,

```
http://example.com/pictures.aspx?ImagePath=ABCDEFGHIJ1234567989KLMNOPQRST==.....
```

E.g.: A random long string of code, but no `.jpg` or `.png` indicating the file name.  When right clicking to save, it shows the image is blocked.

How can I get the images using Android code?

Tks

Comment: It *you* are allowed then use `java.net.URL/URLConnection` or apache http API.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not allowing them to be taken from a website, then it probably shouldn't be taken. That being said, there are a couple of options if you are the owner of the website.

If they are in a database then you can get the url address of them. Also, right clicking anywhere on the page to "View source" should get you some sort of URL of the image.

Comment: Thanks.  However, viewing source doesn't get me the image's URL, but shows up like the one mentioned in my question above, i.e. contains long string of random text but no image name since it doesn't end with an image file extension

Answer (score 0):

This seems more of a web service implementation issue rather than anything andriod specific. Many websites have this feature where you are not meant to retrieve information from the url.

However there should be a corresponding supported web service interface for fetching the metadata of a particular resource. If this is not supported then it's meant to be blocked.

The other trial and error sort of way is to invoke a 3rd party API like oEmbed (or Embed.ly : http://embed.ly/) that would return the metadata of the resource for which you have the URL. These services cover a wide range of websites and their resources.

You can search around in their site or find similar such services that would get you this information. Embed.ly is more of a personal preference due to its exhaustive list of supported sites.